# Cordova navigator.app.backHistory button on html different approach

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, hybrid

I'm building hybrid app with Intel XDK and I need help with back button and it's function. I have only one index.html file. All "pages" are 's and each one have different id. 
I navigate through them using  **activate_subpage("#uib_page_10");**

```
 $(document).on("click", ".firs_div_button", function(evt){
     //#uib_page_10 is div with it's content
     activate_subpage("#uib_page_10");
   var thisPage = 1;
 goBackFunction (thisPage);  //call function and pass it page number  

});

$(document).on("click", ".second_div_button", function(evt){
     //#uib_page_20 is div with it's content
     activate_subpage("#uib_page_20");
 var thisPage = 2;
 goBackFunction (thisPage);  //call function and pass it page number      

});
```

I have set this **EventListener** hardware on back button.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
alert("hello");
navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

This is functional but it does not work as it should, in my case and for my app. 
When I navigate from one page to another (5 pages / divs) and hit back button, sometimes it does not go back to the first page. It just go "back" to history too deep and close the app, without changing the actual page (view) before closing.

Now, I have an idea, but I need help with this. 
I will not use history back, I will use counter and dynamic array for up to 5 elements.

```
 function goBackFunction (getActivePage) {
 var active_page = getActivePage;
 var counter = 0; // init the counter (max is 5)
 var history_list = [counter][active_page];  // empty array
 counter = counter + 1;

 :
 :
 :

}

document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
 //read the array and it's positions then activate:
 activate_subpage("#PAGE_FROM_ARRAY");  
counter = counter - 1;

if (counter == 0) {
  //trigger the app exit when counter get's to 0.
  navigator.app.exitApp();
 }
}
```

This is only idea, not tested. I would like to store list of opened pages in **Array** and when back button is pressed, to activate the pages taken from the **Array** list, backwards.

I do not know how to do this, I'm not a expert :( There is may be batter way to do this. If someone have any suggestion, I will accept it :D

Comment: The functionality of back button relies on how you landed on the current page.If you used 'window.location.replace' to navigate from page1 to page2, then page1 will not be tracked in history and you cannot navigate back to page1 on click of back button in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I save an array in localStorage with all pages navigated and I go back using a pop() on the array. At the moment, it's the best way I got to go back.
This is my code:

// First, create the table "pages"

```
function init_pages_table()
{
    var pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);
    if (!pages.isNew()) 
    {
        pages.drop();
        pages.commit();
    }
    var pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);
    pages.createTable("Pages", ["nome"]);
    // commit the database to localStorage
    // all create/drop/insert/update/delete operations should be committed
    pages.commit();
}
```

// Add a page into the array:

```
function push_pagename(pagename)
{
    var pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);
    if (!pages.tableExists("Pages"))
    {
        init_pages_table();
        pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);
    }
    pages.insert("Pages", {nome: pagename});
    pages.commit();
}
```

// Pop a page form the array:

```
function pop_pagename()
{
    var output = '';
    var id_page = ''
    var pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);        
    var last_page = pages.queryAll("Pages", { limit: 1,
                        sort: [["ID", "DESC"]]
                      });
    $.each(last_page, function(index,value){
                output = value.nome;
                id_page = value.ID;
                return false;
            });       
    var rowdeleted = pages.deleteRows("Pages", {ID: id_page});
    pages.commit();
    return output;
}
```

You can also define functions for set, get, read:

```
function set_backpage(pageurl)
{
    push_pagename(pageurl);
}
function get_backpage()
{
    return pop_pagename();
}
function read_backpage()
{
    var output = '';
    var id_page = ''
    var pages = new localStorageDB("pages", localStorage);        
    var last_page = pages.queryAll("Pages", { limit: 1,
                        sort: [["ID", "DESC"]]
                      });
    $.each(last_page, function(index,value){
                output = value.nome;
                id_page = value.ID;
                return false;
            }); 
    return output;
}
```